# Get all nearby places using MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, maps, mapkit

I'm searching for nearby places using Apple's map kit. The request category though is a string and in my case @"Restaurants". Commenting that out returns no places. How can I display all the places in without filtering the category? In other words get all places available. Thank you in advance.

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"Restaurants";
```

Comment: I don't think it's actually possible.

Comment: in the apple docs it specifies naturalLanguageQuery as "A string containing the desired search item", but I was hoping that someone figured a workaround

Comment: It also specifies "This property can't be nil", even though nil is different from empty, I think we can assume it won't do a search without a specific filter.